SSH connect to network appliance and run command
I have a network appliance that can be connected to with username and password.
On logging in, it shows a login banner (several lines) and then shows a custom shell where one can run only a preset of commands provided by the manufacturer.
What is the best way to connect to this appliance from python script, run commands and get the command output?
Also note that: I need to run a series of commands in one session to be able to get output. For example: first command to change to IP submenu and second command to SET IP.
I tried using Fabric module: to create a connection object and then call connection.run(). But this only presents an interactive shell and not run any commands. Below is example code:
from fabric import Connection
from invoke.exceptions import UnexpectedExit
from invoke.watchers import Responder

def run_network_command(host, username, password, command):
    try:
        conn = Connection(host=host, user=username, connect_kwargs={
                "password": password,
            },
        )
        
        # Create responder for the custom shell prompt
        prompt_pattern = r"\[net-7\.2\] \w+>"
        shell_responder = Responder(
            pattern=prompt_pattern,
            response=f"{command}\n"
        )
        
        # Run command in the custom shell
        result = conn.run(
            command,
            pty=True,
            watchers=[shell_responder]
        )
        
        return result.stdout
        
    except UnexpectedExit as e:
        return f"Error executing command: {str(e)}"
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Connection error: {str(e)}"
    finally:
        try:
            conn.close()
        except:
            pass

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Connection details
    host = "192.168.1.1"
    username = "root"
    password = "pass"
    command = "show version"
    
    # Run command and print output
    output = run_network_command(host, username, password, command)
    print(output)

What is the best way to achieve this?

do you need to interact with the remote system in an interactive way or does running direct commands like ssh user@address 'my command to run' work?

Security note: do not pass the password like this for a production system and instead rely on ssh keys if possible! Providing a plaintext password, while somewhat protected by sshpass, may allow it to appear in logs and tracebacks
If you can install sshpass in your client, while not very elegant, I find subprocess works great in a pinch
import subprocess

def collect_call(user, address, remote_command, password=None, timeout_seconds=30):
    cmd = ["ssh", f"{user}@{address}", remote_command]
    env = None  # env only needed for sshpass
    if password:  # not exclusively ssh keys
        print("warning do not use in production, use keys instead")
        cmd = ["sshpass", "-e"] + cmd  # inject password via wrapper
        env = {"SSHPASS": password}    # avoids password in process args
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True,
        env=env,
    )
    out, err = p.communicate(timeout=timeout_seconds)
    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise OSError(f"failed {{p.returncode}}: {out+err}")
    return out

Next assert the output has some wanted shape and drop anything you don't want

I need to run a series of commands in one session to be able to get output. For example: first command to change to IP submenu and second command to SET IP. Not sure if that can be done with above approach?

hmm, you might be able to pass a block of commands in all at once, just stick 'em all together with '\n' , but interacting like that is generally not great because you have to do it all at once and the shape can change under you without warning (though you can first make sure some version matches, etc. and so fail hard when a release occurs.. it'll still break your tool, but in a known way).. practically, is there another system, such as a web API or feature to accept a complete configuration file? especially setting IP addresses automatically during remote connection can be pretty hairy

What about paramiko?
import paramiko


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(hostname='your_host', port=22, username='your_username',     password='your_password')


stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('your_command')
result = stdout.read()
ssh.close()

print(result.decode())


With Paramiko I would have to do much more output parsing. Ideally I would prefer something higher level. If not, Paramiko is my last option.
